# Change directory in bash script in windows

Tags: windows, bash, path, cd

How can I change my working directory in bash script in windows. I have 
~dp0 = C:\test\docker\windows and I want to change my directory to C:\test\build
So it means 2 levels up and then int o build folder

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

On my system in Git bash the C:\ root is just `/c/` and other dirs from there are whatever they are, so it would be `cd /c/test/build/`.

You could also still say `cd ../../build/`.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

## Since C:\ is mounted by default into /mnt/c this will work.

**Create a .bashrc in your home path by following command:**

```
    echo "BUILDDIR=/mnt/c/test/build" >> ~/.bashrc;source ~/.bashrc
    cd $BUILDDIR         

    # Do your work below for example ./configure.
    ./configure
```

Answer (score -1):

To change the directory using a bash script is just like you would using normal bash.

```
cd "C:/test/build"
echo "You're now in the folder, do what you will."
```

Save the file as .sh and it can be used as such.
Note, when navigation your folders using a bash script remember the directory you'll be starting from is always the home directory.